# ServeRAID error in syslog, is it important?

Tags: rhel, logs, raid

I was checking the logs in server when i came across this message.

```
Nov 4 12:52:05 SERVERNAME ServeRAID Manager Agent: [338] Periodic scan
found one or more critical logical drives: controller 1. Repair as soon as
possible to avoid data loss.
```

1. What does this mean?
2. Is it Critical or can be ignored?
3. If critical how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One of SERVERNAME's disks is failing (or perhaps a software or hardware issue)
2. Yes, unless you don't care this server's data
3. Use the [ServeRAID manager documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/director/v5r2/index.jsp?topic=/serveraid_5.20/fqm0_r_events_storage_serveraid_controller_periodic_scan.html) to find out what is causing the issue and fix it.